# Finding the coefficient in the expansion of 3 variables.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've been set a question to find the coefficient of in front of $x^8z^{-3}y^{12}$ in $(x+y^{-1}+z^2)^{17}$. Hence, how would I expand $(x^a+y^b+z^c)^d$? Trinomial expansions have only just been introduced to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Maybe you mean $x^8y^{-3}z^{12}$?)

The trinomial expansion of $(X+Y+Z)^n$ is $$\sum_{i+j+k=n} {{n}\choose{i,j,k}} X^iY^jZ^k $$
In your case we have $X=x, Y=y^{-1},Z=z^2,n=17$ and we are looking at the term
$$
x^8y^{-3}z^{12}=X^8Y^3Z^6
$$
and thus $i=8,j=3,k=6$. Therefore the coefficient is given by
$$
{{17} \choose {8,3,6}}=\frac{17!}{8! 3! 6!}=2042040
$$